# Database SQL excluding a data

Tags: sql

I have a problem getting data when joining 2 tables, `JOB` and `Application`.

The `Job` table has id, title and description, while the `Application` table has id, applicant and job_id.

I wanted to show the jobs that the applicant **haven't applied** yet

```
ID   TITLE               DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------
2    web developer       some text
3    web designer        some text
4    project manager     some text

ID   applicant  job_id
-----------------------
1       28        2
2        1        2
3        1        3
```

So I tried this query:

```sql
select 
    job.id, job.title ,job.description 
from 
    `job` 
left join 
    `application` on `job`.`id` = `application`.`job` 
where 
    `application`.`applicant` != 28 
    or `application`.`applicant` is null
```

but this just returns all jobs.

Comment: What do you mean by I have not applied? What is "I"?

Comment: @Popeye so the result i wanted is that if the applicant with id 28 is logged in it will show
the jobs that the applicant havent applied

sorry for the grammars and stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
select j.* 
 from `job` j 
where not exists
      (select 1 from `application` a 
        where j.`id` = a.`job` and a.`applicant` = 28)
```

Comment: `SELECT j.*
FROM job j
LEFT JOIN application a ON j.id = a.job_id  AND a.applicant = 1
WHERE a.applicant IS NULL`

so from your answer i got this query but only with join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN`. So, the code should be look like given blow =>

```
SELECT job.id, job.title ,job.description FROM JOB 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT job_id FROM Application);
```